# While restore package.json package getting Error for Method Not Allowed in VS2015?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, visual-studio-2015

I am getting a `Method Not Allowed` error when I restore a package.json in VS2015.

[image]
[image]

This is the log I get:

```
npm ERR! Error: Method Not Allowed
npm ERR!     at errorResponse (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:753:14)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:773:12
npm ERR!     at saved (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:148:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\...\Angular2\Angular2
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code E405
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're trying to do this from VS2015. Visual Studio uses a pre-packaged version of NPM. We can also see by looking at your log that it's using npm 1.4.9, which is super old.

You can navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\` and execute `npm install npm -g` to update it.

You will probably need to tell VS to use a newer version of node. It seem like it's using node 0.10.31, which is ages old. [This guide](https://www.ryadel.com/en/visual-studio-2015-update-nodejs-andor-npm-latest-version/) should help you.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can specify the NPM location you want Visual Studio to use. You can go under `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> External Web Tools` and change the current path. Bumping up `$(PATH)` above `.\node_modules\.bin` should also do the trick.

[image: how to change the location of NPM Visual Studio 2015]

[Source (for updating npm)](https://www.ryadel.com/en/visual-studio-2015-update-nodejs-andor-npm-latest-version/)

[Source (for changing location)](https://medium.com/@frankchen2016/node-js-and-npm-introduction-for-visual-studio-2015-50ed9db8da22)

Comment: While i use this command 
npm install npm@latest -g

I'm getting error as below
silly fetchPackageMetaData error for npm@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...fig-chain","debuglog"'

Comment: There may be some corruption in your cache. Try clearing it with `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: one thing I don't understand while I check version of node and npm in cmd I;m getting latest version such as first cmd screenshot but when I try to restore package in VS2015 i'm getting old version as shown in log

Comment: That's because the command line uses the version of npm located in your PATH environment variable (probably located under C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm). VS uses a pre-packaged version located under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm.

Comment: Any solution to set vs15 to use latest npm location?

Comment: This npm install npm@latest -g  option is not working?

Comment: I meant the edit at the end of my post. But I guess you found it since you posted the same thing haha!

Answer (score 0):

In VS15 Option-->Tool-->Project & Solution-->External Web Tools

Add new path "C:\Program Files\nodejs" set as top all of the above 
Then

Open cmd as administrator go  your solution

Type npm -i

Now you can see node_modules folder

After successfully install npm

Type npm start you can see index.html "Hello Angular" in Lite server